# Parabolic PDE with non-zero boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I'm trying to solve the partial differential equation $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$ on the square $[0,\pi] \times [0,b[$ with initial conditions:

$u(0,t) = 0$

$u(x,0) = \sin(x)$

$u(\pi,t) = \sin(t)$

I know I have to use the separation of variables, and I know exactly how to solve it when $u(\pi,t) = 0$, because I then have $X(0) = X(\pi) = 0$. But know we have $X(\pi)T(t)=sin(t)$, which seems useless to me. Can you help me?

Comment: What is $y$? Shouldn't it be $u(\pi,t)=\sin t$?

Comment: There seems to be something wrong with the condition $u(\pi ,t)=\sin t$ \
since separation of variables gives an exponential time dependence.

Comment: Yeah you're right it's impossible my teacher told me, i misread the question, it was written "If possible"... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Find any function that satisfies the boundary conditions, like $\dfrac{1}{\pi}\,x\sin t$, and let
$$
u(x,t)=v(x,t)+\frac{1}{\pi}\,x\sin t.
$$
Then $v$ satisfies 
$$
\begin{cases}
v_t-v_{xx}=-\dfrac{1}{\pi}\,x\cos t,\\
v(x,0)=\sin x,\\
v(0,t)=v(\pi,t)=0.
\end{cases}
$$
This can be solved by separation of variables looking for a solution of the form
$$
v(x,t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n(t)\sin(n\,x).
$$